# Content of a cell table that fill the entire remaining space

Tags: css, html-table

I have a code similar to the following extract:

```
   <table>
     <tr>
       <td>Some Text <span>other text</span></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>Some other Text <span>some other text 2</span></td>
     </tr>
   </table>
```

Different table rows can have different content length, but obviously cell width is equal between rows.

I would like that texts included in SPAN tag will be long as the entire remaining space of cell table, because it has a colored background. Width:100% does not solve my problem because span text is not placed at the beginning of the cell table.

Is it possible in an easy way?

Answer (score 0):

Add `white-space: nowrap;` style to table.

[Live Demo Here.](http://jsfiddle.net/shijukbabu/KuYuw/3/)

Remove CSS part to see the changes. Also check table width

Comment: Hi, I updated your Fiddle ([link](http://jsfiddle.net/KuYuw/5/) ) to show my situation.
I did not understand why white-space:nowrap should solve my problem but maybe it was unclear what i would like.
I would like that span elements with dotted red bottom border, estend through all remaining cell table, and not only to their content